# Is It Possible to Insert Python's Function Arguments from Batch File?

Tags: python, batch-file

I am wondering if it is possible to insert a function argument in Python from batch file?

For example, I have the following function:

```
def multiply(x,y):
    result = pd.DataFrame([[x*y]], columns = ['Multiplication'])
    return result
```

So my aim is: I want to run this script using a batch file and from that batch file I want to give the argument x and y and later export the result as data frame into csv file using `return.to_csv(r'my path + filename.csv')`

Can we do this by using batch `batch-file`?  Many thanks.

Comment: Could you just `def __main__` that pulls in system args using the `import sys` and `sys.argv[]` that calls this multiply function on the arguments passed into it. Then you would make a batch file that calls this python file with command line arguments?

Comment: Recommending books or off site resources is off topic on StackOverflow. I have downvoted your question just for asking that, and voted for it to be closed.

Comment: my apologies for going off topic. I will keep this in mind. Thanks a lot for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can do it if you use the sys library. lets call your file `multi.py`

```
import sys

def multiply(x,y):
    result = pd.DataFrame([[x*y]], columns = ['Multiplication'])
    return result

print(muliply(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2]))
```

then you will write this in your bat file:

```
python multi.py 2 3
```

and your program will print out to the console the result :)

Comment: 20 seconds ahead of me, nice work +1

Comment: thank you plum :o), i didn't get to test it though...

Comment: I am not going to downvote your answer, but typically we do not answer entirely off topic questions, which this one is clearly. Please keep in mind in future. Even though we earn reputation, it makes it easy for people to ask questions which does not help others at all.

Comment: Ah ok sorry, and thank you. I will keep it in mind :)  It is my first day here answering questions :)